# Lazy objects and limit query object in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

The question is very focused on Lazy Django objects, is a cache of query to which he makes the call, I want to understand how it works according to Django is:

```
#1
data = Query.objects.all()
dato = data[5]
```

is the same as:

```
#2
dato = Query.objecs.all()[5]
```

The question is to understand if the Django cache causes the objects Lazy # 1 is equal to # 2 in the views? or if instead at # 1 will take longer to make the call to all the objects first and then take five?

is more of a theoretical question Django to which I did not understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Internally, a QuerySet can be constructed, filtered, sliced, and generally passed around without actually hitting the database. No database activity actually occurs until you do something to evaluate the queryset.

```
#1
data = User.objects.all()
dato = data[5]

#2
dato = User.objecs.all()[5]

#sql-script
SELECT `auth_user`.`id`,
       `auth_user`.`password`,
       `auth_user`.`last_login`,
       `auth_user`.`is_superuser`,
       `auth_user`.`username`,
       `auth_user`.`first_name`,
       `auth_user`.`last_name`,
       `auth_user`.`email`,
       `auth_user`.`is_staff`,
       `auth_user`.`is_active`,
       `auth_user`.`date_joined`
FROM `auth_user` LIMIT 1
OFFSET 5
```

1. The SQL script for the both queries are same.
2. The snippet #1 will take **higher time** than #2 snippet, because it has two lines for execution.
3. Here, speed is based on **less No.of.Lines execution**.

In order to know Django queries execution time and raw SQL query in terminal use this command `python manage.py shell_plus --print-sql`.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know of how Python is parsed (which isn't a whole lot), these two examples have to do the same thing. When parsing the second, Python will make the same call to `Query.objects.all()` as in the first, and then take the sixth element.

Comment: I understand that do the same, but which is faster? which is more effective? if for example you do a [0:5] is a limit and I think the query should be faster at # 2 but really not by Lazy Objects

Comment: @user987055, I'm saying that they actually execute the same code, so they'll both be exactly the same speed. I haven't used django, but if `Query.objects.all()` returns some sort of lazy object, than both #1 and #2 will only make a single query for the sixth object, and if it doesn't return a lazy object, then both examples will make queries for all objects. AFAIK, Python will translate both examples into pretty much the same byte code.